# Unable to paste into Edit Control Input box in MFC application in Microsoft Server 2019 standard and Server 2012 R2

Tags: winapi, mfc, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2019

I have a MFC application that has 2 input boxes(Edit Control). This application is called from MSI Custom action during installation. When I try to paste(Ctrl + V and Right click -> Paste) into those input boxes, It is not working. But I can copy paste contents of input boxes to other applications. Copy paste works fine when application is run standalone but not works when msi custom action calls.This only happens in Windows Server 2019 Standard and Windows Server 2012 R2.

I tried using `CEdit::Paste()` function for Ctrl + V keypressdown action. Then tried to get Clipboard contents using `OpenClipboard()` function. But I got nothing from clipboard.

Comment: Check if you can copy&paste when you launch a NotePad´.exe elevated. You may have a problem with the process isolation.

Comment: Check if you have a Ctrl+V accelerator in your resource file. If so it should be either processed (eg forwarded to your edit control - better send a `WM_PASTE` message rather than work with the clipboard), or removed completely (the default implementation of Ctrl+V is paste).

Comment: Can you copy/paste from/to the edit controls themselves, just inside the application?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, I can copy paste within edit controls and each other.

Comment: @xMRi Tried it, It is also not working!

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I don't have any accelerators